# Configuration of two different networks

Tags: networking

May be the question is a little silly but I'm rookie into this.
I have one laptop which i use in my home and in my work. In home I use internet from one ISP and in work i use another internet connection.

Question is how to make 2 Network Connections, so when I go in home or in office I don't want to change every time my IP, DNS, MASK, etc ...
OS is Windows 7.

EDIT:

So everything is in Alternative... When I go in home I don't have problems- DHCP working fine. Problem is in office and doesn't want to use this configuration. Here is the picture.

[image]

This is what i get whit all correct information in Alternative Connection tab when i plug in cable with fixed IP

Comment: Ideally, make sure both networks have a DHCP server set up, and leave your laptop set for DHCP.

Comment: They are not both DHCP.. one is DHCP only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one is fixed IP and the other is DHCP you can use the Alternate Configuration tab to setup your fixed IP networking then when it sees a DHCP server at the other location it will ignore the Alternate Configuration and get an IP from the DHCP server instead. The steps below will get you going if this is the case. If, however, you need multiple fixed IP or DHCP networks then there are freeware apps out there that will let you switch settings easy enough.

Hit Start and type in ***Network Connections*** 
Right click on your active connection and select properties.
In the middle of the Networking tab double click the ***Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP\IPv4)*** item
If you are not setup for DHCP select ***Obtain an IP address automatically***
You should see a new tab called ***Alternate Configuration***
On this tab configure your fixed IP network
Click the OK button to save your changes and exit

At this point when you connect to your DHCP enabled network the OS will grab an IP and use it but when it connects to a network without DHCP it will use the Alternate Configuration IP info.

Comment: Yes, one is DHCP other is fixed IP. In network control panel i have Network Connection and Wireless Connection icons. On network connection i don't have Alternate Configuration, but in Wireless connection i have ot

Comment: The steps assume you are using one network connection. Are you using wireless or wired or do you switch between both?

Comment: Ah, i see now. Because i writet IP, DNS ... i don't have this tab...When i check Öbtain automatically IP adress the Alternate tab is shown

Comment: Right put your fixed IP info on the new tab. The OS will switch between them assuming there is no DHCP server on the network you want to use fixed IP.

Comment: So i made it. Now I have "Obtain an IP adress automatically" and on Alternate Configuration tam "User configured" I wrote my IP,DNS,MASK, Gateway..

Comment: Thank you for help i hope will work when i go home later. Thank's again.

Comment: doesn't work. I mean when i go home and plug LAN cable is work. But when i came into my office and plug my LAN cable doesn't work. Added me wrong IP

Comment: Which is dynamic IP and which is fixed?

Comment: In my home is DHCP and when i go home and plug the cable is work. On next day when i back in office with fixed IP network doesn't work and i must enter again my IP etc..

Comment: And the fixed IP information is entered in the Alternate Configuration tab and the General tab is set to **Obtain an IP address automatically**? When you move between locations you shouldn't have to touch anything. It should be automatic. Also, you are turning your computer off between locations and not just putting it to sleep right?

Comment: Yes, everything is like this.

Comment: So everything is still in the alternate configuration tab when you have to go in and put it also in the general tab?

Comment: I edited my first post